# Can't add iframe to paragraph - iframe is stripped for attributes

Tags: 8

I have a problem with adding an iframe to a paragraph.

In Text formats and editors, I have checked "Limit allowed HTML-tags" and then added `<iframe>` to allowed tags.

But when adding an iframe tag with attributes to the CKEditor, all attributes are removed and only the tag is remaining.

When I uncheck "Limit allowed HTML-tags", the iframe is shown as expected but I do want to restrict HTML tags.

Is this a bug or am I adding the tag wrong?

[image: Allowed tags]

[image: Pasted]

[image: iframe stripped]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your output:

```
<p><iframe></iframe></p>
```

It's likely you need to specify the allowed attributes as well under *Limit allowed HTML-tags*. e.g.

```
<iframe width height src etc>
```

Comment: And what if I want to allow specific values for the tags? Like src='youtube.com/*'?

Comment: I don't know if ckeditor supports that, I'd check their documentation directly: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules.html